Name for a sequence of open sets, each dense in the complement of the previous ones in the subspace topology
Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $\mathfrak{U} = \langle U_\alpha:\alpha\in\gamma\rangle$ be a sequence of non-empty open subsets of $X$ of length $\gamma$ ($\gamma$ an ordinal). Say (for now) that $\mathfrak{U}$ is an inductively dense $\gamma$-sequence iff for each $\alpha<\gamma$, $U_\alpha\cap (X-\cup_{\beta<\alpha}U_\beta)$ is dense in $X-\cup_{\beta<\alpha}U_\beta$ for the subspace topology.
Is there a standard name for these inductively dense $\gamma$-sequences ? Does someone know where I can learn about this topic ?
Notice that if $X$ is second countable and $\mathfrak{U}$ is an inductively dense $\gamma$-sequence, then $\gamma$ is countable. Indeed, $U_\alpha$ is not contained in $\cup_{\beta<\alpha}U_\beta$ when $\alpha<\gamma$, hence there is a member of the countable base which is contained in $U_\alpha$ but not in $\cup_{\beta<\alpha}U_\beta$. On the other hand, it is easy to define an inductively dense $\gamma$-sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ for any $\gamma<\omega_1$. For instance, we may start with the ordinal $\omega^\gamma$ (ordinal exponentiation) and inductively take the isolated points in $U_\alpha$ as in the Cantor derivative, which yields an inductively dense $\gamma$-sequence. Embed $\omega^\gamma$ in $\mathbb{R}$ to finish.
